# Mantis and Redmine, which one is better for issue tracking?

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking, mantis

I consider to use Mantis or Redmine to manage projects. (Issue Tracking)

I know both are really good.

For now, I won't connect it with SVN or Git.
(It may happen later)

The main purpose is issue tracking on business with co-workers.

Please recommend one of them, or you can recommend the other one.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any specific features you need? It would help in choosing between the two.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can recommend redmine. I've been using it for more than 2 years, with 25-50 simultaneous users and more than 50 projects.

I went through a lot of updates without ever having any problems.

The database is properly normalized, so if you ever need to retrieve any data, you will be able to do so.

Numerous plugins exists which may cover special needs if there are any.

---

Edit: In the meantime, I had to change over to Jira, but I'd go back to redmine anytime if I could.

Comment: Another vote for Redmine here, the feature list of the two are very similar but Mantis is advertised as a bug tracker tool whereas Redmine is more a Project/Configuration management tool including an excellent bug tracker.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Even today in 2019, I find "Redmine" to be the best open source & self-hosted solution for Issue Tracking & Project Management. 
P.S. Chili Project is not maintained anymore, so original Redmine is the way to go.

Comment: @khalid You're right, I removed the chiliproject reference as it is obsolete now.

Answer (score 7):

Never used Redmine, but we've been using Mantis for about 7-8 years for many projects for our distributed team. One of the benefits is its simplicity. We've even wrote a couple of our own extensions, e.g. widely used in our process Kanban board (one of the Agile approaches).

Sometimes I think it looks slightly outdated among other modern tools but it really works for us and we can extend it with our own PHP code.